# Is it possible to use Code::Blocks as IDE for mobile apps developing?

Tags: android, c++, eclipse

I'm using Code::Blocks as my IDE and is programming in C++/SDL and was wondering about if the Code::Blocks IDE really can create more advanced stuff like a mobile app?

Or if I need another more advanced IDE like Eclipse to install to create a mobile app.

It would be great if it was possible to actually create a mobile app with Code::Blocks. I mean Code::Blocks is really easy to use and setup without getting any errors.

So I thought you guys who knows this very well could tell me that. Thanks for replies :)

Comment: Does Code::Blocks allow you to code in Java? And probably it would be easier with Eclipse, because Android built a plugin for Eclipse to build Android apps, even if your IDE supports Java.

Comment: I'm don't think Code::Blocks can allow me to code in Java. But if I install Eclipse then. Is it possible to code in C++/SDL?

Comment: I know you can use Eclipse to code C++, though you may have to install 2 versions.

Comment: Do you think you can give me the download links to the 2 versions? Then? :)

Comment: Eclipse is no longer officially supported for Android development, you should use Android Studio. Android Studio is also easy to setup and use (it doesn't even require an installation), however it is a big memory hogger. Android Studio also allows you to code in C/C++ using Android NDK.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has seperate work environmnet for android development.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Also there is one for both ios and Android 
https://blogs.oracle.com/fusionmiddleware/entry/eclipse_android_ios_oracle_enterprise